# Overriding Apache auth directive

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication, virtualhost

I'm trying to allow public access to a method that generates a WSDL-file for our API. The rest of the site is behind basic auth protection. Can you guys take a look at the following virtual-host configuration and see why the override does not take place?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName xyz.mydomain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/dev/public

        <Directory /var/www/dev/public>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all

                SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV testing
        </Directory>

        <Location />
                AuthName "XYZ Development Server"
                AuthType Basic
                AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/xyz.passwd
                Require valid-user
        </Location> 

        <Location /api/soap/wsdl>
           Satisfy Any
           allow from all
        </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Location (and LocationMatch) directive can use Regular Expression.  Why not use a Location match with a regex to *not* match the API page you are hosting.  For example:

```
<LocationMatch "(?!/api/soap/wsdl)">
  AuthName "XYZ Development Server"
  AuthType Basic
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/xyz.passwd
  Require valid-user
</LocationMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need:

```
Satisfy any
allow from all
```

in a Directory Block rather than a Location Block for it to be considered.

Comment: Hmm... but I don't want to protect files, but rather a location (or all locations except a specific one). The problem is that I use a FrontController pattern, so /api/soap/wsdl is rewritten to index.php and Zend Framework routes it from there... How would you propose that I create a .htaccess-file that would allow this?

Comment: That would be the problem then.  Since index.php is within your authentication realm.  What you might be able to do is put a symlink to index.php in an unprotected directory and do something like    Alias /unprotected.php /path/to/symlinked/index.php and change your rewrite for the wdsl to use unprotected.php

Your rewrite changes your authentication realm which is why your satisfy any/allow from all isn't working.  It does actually work (I tested it here), but, when you do the rewrite, your other rules take over.